# How can I get a row in excel to be highlighted dynamically using conditional formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a table with a column that is a data driven list. I would like the row to change colour based upon whatever item I pick from that drop down list. I don't want to have to run the conditional formatting menu option every time I want them to color. I would like it to be a different colour depending on the list item that I choose.

I would also like to be able add to the table as time goes on and pull down that column so I can use that in additional rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it - change the reference to =$A1="yes" so excel knows to select the row

Answer (score 0):

Example using the contents of A1 and A2 to format the entire of rows 1 and 2 respectively:

1. Select the entire of rows 1 and 2 by clicking and dragging on the row header.
2. Click `Format` > `Conditional Formatting...`
3. Add rule by clicking on `+` icon
4. Set style to `Classic`
5. Select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
6. Type formula `=$A1="yes"`. The `$` creates an absolute column reference. This means that for every cell in each row, rather than changing the formula automatically, Excel will still use column A to choose the formatting e.g. the formatting for B1 still depends on A1 (rather than on B1 if we'd left off the `$`). We didn't put a `$` before the row number, so Excel will automatically change the formula for row 2 so that, for example, the formatting for B2 depends on A2. (If we'd put a `$` before the row number i.e. $A$1, the formatting for B2 would depend on A1 instead.)
7. Now whenever A1 has the value `yes` row A will use the format chosen, and whenever B1 has the value `yes` row B will use the format chosen.
8. For each value you'd like to trigger a certain format, add more rules to match the value to a certain format.

*N.B. menu options from Excel for Mac v15 but should be similar in other versions.*

Comment: Ok yup, I understand that, but how do I apply that to a sheet that already has 100 rows? I don't want to go through row by row...

Comment: I got it - see answer

Comment: Hi @Kevin. I didn't realise you wanted to use a multi-row selection, so I've updated the answer to reflect this. Would be grateful if you would accept it. Thanks.